# How to prevent the monkey from clicking on the title bar on Android phone emulator?

Tags: android, monkey

I run the monkey on Android emulator from Windows command line with the following command:

```
adb shell monkey -p <my package name> --monitor-native-crashes --kill-process-after-error --pct-touch 100 1000000000
```

but it clicks not only on the app, but also on the phone title bar changing various phone settings and making the phone glitch. Is it possible to prevent it from this?